# Does Mac OS X Lion / 10.7 support UEFI 2.0?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, efi, osx-lion

I've been hoping for a while that Mac would move to UEFI 2.0 from the older EFI 1.x spec (for many reasons, such as an ability to boot Windows natively on UEFI *without* running it under bios emulation, as in Bootcamp). Is this true with Lion / 10.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Boot Camp is still required in Lion. This would have to be a **firmware** update for EFI to change.